# Strange TCP dump sequence

Tags: tcp, connection, reset, seq

I have an intermittent but reproducible issue with a TCP connection.
Sender (port 64613) is running on a Windows box while the receiver (port 14004) is on a RedHat 6 host.
Ports are not part of the picture: the same issue happens with different ports.

The connection works fine for over a minute or so, with data and acknowledgement packets flowing normally.

But then the following behavior happens: the Wireshark capture on the sender side shows a packet being sent (seq=3020828):

```
    57788   2018-07-16 15:36:20.552618000            10.245.40.74     10.245.54.13     TCP      2974            64613 -> 14004 [ACK] Seq=3020828 Ack=73535403 Win=65536 Len=2920
```

for which no ACK is ever received back. 
The sender also keeps re-transmitting it in a smaller packet, up to 5 times before eventually giving up the connection:

```
    58376   2018-07-16 15:36:20.851770000             10.245.40.74     10.245.54.13     TCP      1514     [TCP Retransmission] 64613 -> 14004 [ACK] Seq=3020828 Ack=74313583 Win=1296 Len=1460
    58378   2018-07-16 15:36:21.101721000             10.245.54.13     10.245.40.74     TCP      1350            14004 -> 64613 [PSH, ACK] Seq=74313583 Ack=3020828 Win=4096 Len=1296 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
    ...
    60992   2018-07-16 15:36:22.652682000             10.245.40.74     10.245.54.13     TCP      1514     [TCP Retransmission] 64613 -> 14004 [ACK] Seq=3020828 Ack=77762103 Win=1296 Len=1460
    60994   2018-07-16 15:36:22.658427000             10.245.54.13     10.245.40.74     TCP      1514            14004 -> 64613 [ACK] Seq=77762103 Ack=3020828 Win=4096 Len=1460 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
    ...
    91947   2018-07-16 15:36:39.456903000             10.245.40.74     10.245.54.13     TCP      54            64613 -> 14004 [RST, ACK] Seq=3022288 Ack=118789563 Win=0 Len=0
```

The tcpcap on the receiver side shows the packet being received (just in smaller splits, due to intermediate network device):

```
    13573   2018-07-16 15:36:20.526327000            10.245.40.74     10.245.54.13     TCP      1514            64613 -> 14004 [ACK] Seq=3020828 Ack=73535403 Win=65536 Len=1460
    13575   2018-07-16 15:36:20.526360000            10.245.40.74     10.245.54.13     TCP      1514            64613 -> 14004 [ACK] Seq=3022288 Ack=73535403 Win=65536 Len=1460
```

Also, the retransmitted packets are received fine, up to the final RESET packet:

```
    13878   2018-07-16 15:36:20.825430000             10.245.40.74     10.245.54.13     TCP      1514     [TCP Retransmission] 64613 -> 14004 [ACK] Seq=3020828 Ack=74313583 Win=1296 Len=1460
    18810   2018-07-16 15:36:36.047313000             10.245.54.13     10.245.40.74     TCP      29254            14004 -> 64613 [ACK] Seq=114189103 Ack=3020828 Win=20480 Len=29200 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
    ...
    13991   2018-07-16 15:36:21.425465000             10.245.40.74     10.245.54.13     TCP      1514     [TCP Retransmission] 64613 -> 14004 [ACK] Seq=3020828 Ack=74834803 Win=1296 Len=1460
    13993   2018-07-16 15:36:21.433178000             10.245.54.13     10.245.40.74     TCP      27794            14004 -> 64613 [ACK] Seq=74834803 Ack=3020828 Win=4096 Len=27740 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
    ...
    14388   2018-07-16 15:36:22.626436000             10.245.40.74     10.245.54.13     TCP      1514     [TCP Retransmission] 64613 -> 14004 [ACK] Seq=3020828 Ack=77762103 Win=1296 Len=1460
    14390   2018-07-16 15:36:22.632029000             10.245.54.13     10.245.40.74     TCP      32174            14004 -> 64613 [PSH, ACK] Seq=77762103 Ack=3020828 Win=4096 Len=32120 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
    ...
    19416   2018-07-16 15:36:39.431628000             10.245.40.74     10.245.54.13     TCP      60            64613 -> 14004 [RST] Seq=3020828 Win=0 Len=0
```

As you can see above, every time the receiver replies with the ACK message for the previous sequential number:
ACK for 3020828 instead of the new one (3020828 + 1460).

Eventually, the connection drops.

What could be a reason for the receiver to pick up new packets but producing ACKs for previous seq number?

Answer (score 0):

> What could be a reason for the receiver to pick up new packets but producing ACKs for previous seq number?

I would suggest that the recipient (i.e. the application at the RedHat system) has stopped reading the data. This will fill up the socket buffer and once the socket buffer is full no more data will be accepted by the OS kernel. The application is still writing though data to the original sender. But since the applications read socket buffer is full only the ACK for the last (and still unread) data in the socket buffer will be send together with the data written to the original sender.

Comment: if this was the case, wouldn't both TCP captures have included at least a "TCP Zero Window" control message, from the receiver back to the sender, notifying the receive window is full?

Comment: @user3239967: I don't know why it does not get to zero but the announced window size is at least going down from 20480 to 4096.

Comment: Thanks, Steffen. I'm not quite conviced yet: do you imply in such scenario TCP won't allow for a temporary slowdown of the receiver?

Expected behavior:
- if the recv window is not full (indeed Win=4096 >> PacketLen=1460), the packet shall be received and acknowledged
- if the recv window is full, the sender shall be notified and flow-control can kick in

What we observe here:
The window has enough room, yet the packet is silently dropped at receiver side) and the sender is not notified.
As a consequence, after an arbitrary number of useless retransmission, the connection is ceased.

Comment: @user3239967: I'm not convinced either but that was the best explanation I could come up with. Maybe there is also some global limit, i.e. there would be space in the specific socket buffer (so that the window does not gets zero) but it hit the limit how much memory all the buffers together could take and thus the packets gets dropped.